# Почему во многих крупных компаниях, в чатах используют contenteditable="true"?

Tags: html, css, html5

В наборе сообщение VK, Slack, Asana, используют именно такой способ вставки текста?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что это единственный способ отображения форматированного теста с картинками так, чтобы он был редактируемый и внутри показывался курсор. Конечно, можно что-нибудь намутить с позиционированием инпута, но это лишняя и довольно сложная возня. Проще накручивать желаемый функционал на contenteditable, тем более, это одна из древнейших браузерных фич (хотя у неё и [есть минусы](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480)).

Comment: Qwertiy, а какие проблемы у <textarea>, что с ним не так?

Comment: @Air, а покажешь, как выделить одно слово в textarea жирным или поставить после слова смайлик-картинку внутри текста в textarea?

Comment: ))))  все понял... вспомнил, видел вопрос на тему выделить одно слово в <textarea>...  весомый аргумент... ))