# Как реализовать возможность делать текст жирным и настраивать абзацы в text-area?

Tags: php, html, css

Как сделать возможным в textarea переносить строки, делать текст жирным (Местами), буду благодарен за любую информацию :)

Comment: https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/741375/Почему-во-многих-крупных-компаниях-в-чатах-используют-contenteditable-true/741382#comment1133642_741382  посмотри ответ, может что-то для себя подчеркнешь

Answer (score 4):

Это можно сделать в div с атрибутом contenteditable.

```html
 <div contenteditable>Тут <b><u>ваш текст</u></b></div>
```

Comment: Жирность и подчеркивание переносятся на остальные слова/строки

Comment: быстрые кнопки на клавиатуре - никто не отменял (`ctrl` + `b`\`u`'`i`'). Плюс к этому можно прикрутить какую-нибудь фигню на jquery, которая будет обрамлять тегами выделенный текст

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, что такая возможность есть в textarea. 
Я бы посоветовал использовать вместо textarea обычный div. А в нем уже стилизовать элементы (добавить кнопочки, которые по нажатию будут оборачивать выделенный текст в `<span style="font-weight: bold">` с  или в `<p>`, в зависимости от того что вам надо). а потом уже средствами js вытягивать из этого дива содержимое.
Мне кажется, это самый простой метод))))))

Comment: Уважаемый, а как в прстом div  можно набирать текст?

Comment: по клику заменять на input, может?

Comment: почитай, будет полезно https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Общие_атрибуты/contenteditable

Comment: Чем этот ответ лучше соседнего?